# lsd from snap not working

Tags: 18.04, ls

I tried to install [LSD](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd), from snap, but after installation I tried to run it with lsd, and I got the error

`cannot open directory'.': Permission denied (os error 13)`

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Comment: `snap` apps are confined and probably don't have access to your home folder like that.  If you read further down that page you can download the `lsd` .deb file and install it with dpkg that should work for you.

Comment: I actually tried that but cannot find the file specified, `lsd_7.2.0_amd64.deb`

Comment: You have to download it from the [release](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd/releases) page.

Comment: It is a [known bug](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd/issues/79).